# Filtering a Collection

Tags: powerapps

Good morning,
I have watched hours of videos and cannot find the one I need to help me with a syntax issue for filtering a collection based on a dropdown value. I have a drop down that houses the categories for a record. I want to create a collection based on the value selected in the dropdown. Here is the OnSelect function I have written.

```
ClearCollect(
    colMassEdit,
        (Filter(
            RBI_User_Actions,
        ESA_Action = MassEditDrp.SelectedText
    ))
)
```

the = sign between ESA_Action and MassEDitDrp is my syntax error.

ESA_Action is a text field

MassEditDrp is a text field

The collection will not build when I add the filter component.  Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SelectedText property is a record that contains all the properties from the input. If you want the value that is being shown in the dropdown, you can use the `.Value` accessor to retrieve it, so your expression would be as follows:

```
ClearCollect(
    colMassEdit,
    Filter(
        RBI_User_Actions,
        ESA_Action = MassEditDrp.SelectedText.Value
    )
)
```